# Collation error - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I have several databases on a SQL Server instance. I have certain queries that extract information simultaneously these databases. It turns out that after restoring of one of the databases (but that came from another server), these queries gives a `COLLATION` error. I realized then that this "new" database has a different `COLLATION`, so that forces me to use the `COLLATE` for each respective column in these queries. The problem is I have many queries and it would not be practical to make this change on all. I have way to change Database `COLLATION`, as well as all needed columns? I already tried to change the Database but it seems that columns `COLLATION` remain the same...

Comment: It is possible, when I restore database select the collation?

Answer (score 0):

If the collation for individual columns are not set to `Database default`, you should change them one by one.

Comment: I try set some columns to `Database default` but they still with old collation...

Comment: Change the collation for one column to the collation you want to be. See if that column works.

Comment: I don't know why but it always came back to the old collation.

Comment: That's strange. Never had such a problem